# NodeMCU - enable UART1/2 on ESP32

Tags: nodemcu, esp32

I've build firmware as described here: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev-esp32/build/

But I cannot get hardware UART 1 or 2 working. Is there any particular component that has to be enabled (and it's not enabled by default) in order to get it working?

here is my test code:

```
uart_id = 2

local function on_data(data)
    print("IN: ", tostring(data))
end

local function on_error(data)
    print("ERR: ", tostring(data))
end

local cnt = 0;
local function on_timer()
    print(". "..cnt)
    cnt = cnt + 1
    uart.write(uart_id, "# " .. cnt .. "\n")
end

local tmrObj = tmr.create()
tmrObj:register(5000, tmr.ALARM_AUTO, on_timer)
tmrObj:start()

uart.setup(uart_id, 115200, 8, uart.PARITY_NONE, uart.STOPBITS_1, 1)
uart.on(uart_id, "data", '\r', on_data)
uart.on(uart_id, "error", on_error)
uart.setmode(uart_id, uart.MODE_UART)
uart.start(uart_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firmware is OK, `uart.setup` was incorrect. PINs were missing, and for some reason default PINs did not work, this one is fine:

```
uart.setup(uart_id, 115200, 8, uart.PARITY_NONE, uart.STOPBITS_1, {rx = 16, tx = 17})
```

Comment: Great you got that fixed. If you think our documentation is missing something then please raise a PR to improve it.

Comment: Documentation suggest, that pins are optional in setup method, this could be improved. I know that you can assign any PIN, but you could swap from {rx = 17, tx = 16} to {rx = 16, tx = 17}, in such case documentation would reflect markings on dev board.